# how to keep scroll down by default when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php

i have developed one to one chat with ajax and php now please can any one tell me how keep my chat window down scroll bottom by defualt when new message post or when page is loaded message is coming from database

```
       function getmsg(){
          msg = document.getElementById('msg').value

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('msg').value = '';
         }

       }
       if(msg==''){
         xmlhttp.open("GET","chat",true);
         xmlhttp.send();   
       }else{
        xmlhttp.open("GET","chat?message="+msg,true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }

 }


<body onload="getmsg();">


<div class="header">
```

```
    <div id="chat_box" class="chat_window"><div class="top_menu"><div class="buttons"><div class="button close"></div><div class="button minimize"></div><div class="button maximize"></div></div><div class="title">Messaging about order-id: ODR-46</div></div>


        <div id="your_div">
            <ul class="messages" >
           <li id="suggestion">

              messages will show here coming from database
           </li>


       </ul>

     </div>




       <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix"><div class="message_input_wrapper"><input class="message_input" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('send').click()" id="msg" placeholder="Type your message here..." /></div><a  id="send" onclick="return getmsg();" href="#tab"><div class="send_message"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text" >Send</div></div></a></div></div><div class="message_template"><div class="avatar"></div><div class="text_wrapper"><div class="text"></div></div></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same issue with a chat application.

You could set an id (or use any other selector you wish) on your messages list, meaning the element that will contain your messages (ul in this case), then do the following whenever you receive a new message or when you initially get your messages:

```
...
var msgList = document.getElementById("msg-list");
msgList.scrollTop = msgList.scrollHeight;
...
```

One thing to note is that your container element (once again in this case the `<ul>` will have to have a specified height and `overflow:scroll` in your css.

If you don't want to specify a set height for your container element and/or set the overflow of the the element you can just scroll to the bottom of the body:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked i have spend two days to solve this problem –